# best way to create UI java apps?

Tags: java, user-interface

I've come across Netbeans but is there any tools out there that lets you build things event driven ?

I'm looking for a feature like being able to drag and drop UI components, and add methods to buttons directly by double clicking it (kinda like visualbasic) and viewing the source.

Comment: You came across NetBeans, but did you actually try it out to build a GUI? Because the things that you mention are exactly what you can do with NetBeans' GUI builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Netbean you have **Matisse**. See [Designing a Swing GUI in NetBeans IDE](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart-gui.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Eclipse + [Jigloo GUI Builder](http://www.cloudgarden.com) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

There's the [Java Visual Editor](http://www.eclipse.org/vep/).

This is nice if you're used to (or are considering using) [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/), which in itself is a *very* popular Java IDE.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA features a nice [GUI builder](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/gui_builder.html) capable of using several layout managers. It's available in the open source community edition. I personally hate GUI builder and prefer more flexible solution like manually coding the layout with the all powerful and easy to use [MiG Layout](http://www.miglayout.com/).